# Zer0-dimensional, countable, 1st countable T1 space is metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Show that every countable, first countable, zero-dimensional T1 space $X$ is metrizable.**

I know that T1 space means that all its singletons are closed. Also, zero-dimensional means that $X$ has a basis formed by all the clopen sets.

Moreover, I know that if I prove that the space is regular with a countable basis, then that implies it's normal, and if it's normal and second countable, then that implies metrizable.

I feel like I'm making this too complicated, and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Not that I know topology, but a zero dimensional T1 space sounds like discrete space.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...but I'm not sure either

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Indeed, every discrete space is a zero-dimensional T$_1$-space. On the other hand, the space of irrational numbers (topologized as a subspace of the real line) is a zero-dimensional T$_1$-space but is not discrete.

Comment: I recommend you roll back your edit. It is trivial that a discrete space is metrizable; just define $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\ne y$.

Comment: Hint: Zero-dimensional implies regular. Another hint: countable + first countable implies second countable.

Comment: Does completely regular imply regular? I proved that zero-dimensional space implies completely regular space.